# Elegant way to test list of if statements in Python

Tags: python, if-statement, logic

I have some spreadsheets represented as a list of lists in python, and I'm generating output from those.

However, I end up with some really ugly code when I have to omit sections of the sheet, such as: `if not "string" in currentline[index] and not "string2" in currentline[index] and not`... and so on.

Is it possible to represent all the conditions as a list of tuples, say `omit = [(0, "foo"), (5,"bar)]` and then have one if statement that checks of both statements are false?

If I have these two lists:

```
list = [["bar","baz","foo","bar"],["foo","bar","baz","foo","bar"]]
omit = [(0,"foo"),(4,"bar")]
```

and I only want the first one to print, I need an if statement to test every condition inside `omit` somehow, something like:

```
for idx, condition in enumerate(omit):
    a, b = omit[idx]
    if list[a] != omit[b] for all pairs of a and b in omit:
        print list
```

Comment: Check out `all()` and `any()` perhaps you can use them

Comment: You've provided the input and desired output, but you haven't explained the desired correlation between them.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Yes, that's a flaw in my example...

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Sorry! Basically, I want to find all the lists that do not match any of the strings in the omit list at the index position specified by the index list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `any` and a generator expression:

```
>>> seq = [["bar","baz","foo","bar"],["foo","bar","baz","foo","bar"]]
>>> omit = [(0,"foo"),(4,"bar")]
>>> for x in seq:
...     if not any(i < len(x) and x[i] == v for i,v in omit):
...         print(x)
...         
['bar', 'baz', 'foo', 'bar']
```

The `i < len(x)` is necessary so that we don't try accessing element #4 in a list that doesn't have one.

This version demands that neither of the `omit` conditions is met; if you only want to omit sublists if both conditions are met, replace `any` with `all`.

Answer (score -1):

Use `any` and `all` for dynamically-generated lists of predicates.

They each take an iterable of objects and return whether `any` or `all` of them are True -- and they work lazily.

So, for example:

```
any([False, False, False]) is False
all([True, True, True]) is True
any([False, False, True]) is True
```

The beautiful part comes when you use 'em with generators.

```
any(i % 2 == 0 for i in range(50)) is True
```

Here, you can use these operators with your data structures.

```
for row in rows:
    if any(row[idx] == omittable for idx, omittable in omit):
        print 'naw uh'
```